# How to understand async vs sync in Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm currently reading through Spring AMQP's [official sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/main/helloworld) along with it's corresponding explanations from [Spring AMQP docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#hello-world-sample). The project involves an **sync** and **async** version, and the two only differs slightly. Here's the async version:

##### Producer config:

```
@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {

  protected final String helloWorldQueueName = "hello.world.queue";

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setRoutingKey(this.helloWorldQueueName);

    return template;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public ScheduledProducer scheduledProducer() {
    return new ScheduledProducer();
  }

  @Bean
  public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
    return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  static class ScheduledProducer {

    @Autowired
    private volatile RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
    public void sendMessage() {
      rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("Hello World " + counter.incrementAndGet());
    }
  }
}
```

##### Consumer config:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {

  protected final String helloWorldQueueName = "hello.world.queue";

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(this.helloWorldQueueName);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new HelloWorldHandler()));

    return container;
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setRoutingKey(this.helloWorldQueueName);
    template.setDefaultReceiveQueue(this.helloWorldQueueName);

    return template;
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue helloWorldQueue() {
    return new Queue(this.helloWorldQueueName);
  }
}
```

##### HelloWorldHandler:

```
public class HelloWorldHandler {

  public void handleMessage(String text) {
    System.out.println("Received: " + text);
  }
}
```

As the docs explains:

> Since this sample demonstrates asynchronous message reception, the producing side is designed to continuously send messages (if it were a message-per-execution model like the synchronous version, it would not be quite so obvious that it is, in fact, a message-driven consumer). The component responsible for continuously sending messages is defined as an inner class within the ProducerConfiguration. It is configured to run every three seconds.

I failed to understand what's "async" about this code, since, from my understanding, in a basic "synchronous fashion", operations like `amqpTemplate.converAndSend()` and `amqpTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` already peforms Rabbitmq's async actions, neither producer nor consumer are blocking when sending/receiving messages.

So, how's async in this example manifested? And how to understand async vs sync in the Spring AMQP context?

Comment: The receiving is async due to the messagelistener, the `receiveAndConvert` is blocking as it waits until a message is received. Basically the difference is push vs. pull.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks for tuning in. Can you elaborate more on the `messageListener` with  `receiveAndConvert` with push and pull model? I'm still unsure of the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With async, the `MessageListener` is invoked by the framework; messages arrive whenever they are available.

With sync, the application calls a receive method which either returns immediately if no message is available, or blocks until a message arrives or a timeout expires.

In the sync case, the application controls when messages are received, with async, the framework is in control.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As M. Deinum mentioned push vs pull in the comment section, I'd assume the async case is using the __push API__ where the framework takes care of the underlying subscription implemetation. While the sync case, using the __pull API__, enable the application to be able to manually call `amqpTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` method and receive message?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am not sure why you needed more elaboration.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the whole messaging stuff, and wanted to be certain of things, anyways, thank you so much!